# What is the correct way to send email when Jenkins Workflow job fails or is unstable?

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees, jenkins-workflow

I know there is a checkbox to enable email in other job types, but not Workflow. What is the correct way to enable emails sending on failed/unstable builds in a workflow job? I tried wrapping the whole thing in a try/catch block but that interferes with the coloring on the Cloudbees stage view for the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try-catch the steps that could fail (`sh` mainly if you are using Maven or similar) and use `mail` to send the notification, then re-throw the caught exception.

Comment: Yep, re-throwing the exception is what I was missing

Comment: Though I think wrapping the whole thing in a try/catch is the best approach rather than multiple try/catch blocks both to reduce bloat and reduce the risk of errors not being caught.

Comment: How can i avoid mail notification from being sent, when a job is canceled by another newer job of the same workflow (in a throttled stage)?

Comment: Didn't try it, but you could check if the caught exception is  `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException` and one of its `causes` is `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.StageStepExecution.CanceledCause`, if so, then skip the `mail` step.